# VBA function fails when inserting values into Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm totally stumped on why this isn't returning a value. This set of `functions` is supposed to return the `SUM` of all the `ASCII values` in a `String`. The `String` and `Number arrays` build properly and the `SUM function` works on the `Array`, however when it tries to assign that summed value to the return variable, it fails.

By "it fails" I mean that the code does not step to the sum line and the function returns `#VALUE!` to the worksheet. Everything else checks out in the `immediate window` and steps through properly until the last line. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
Private Function StringToCharArray(ByRef sIn As String) As String()

    StringToCharArray = Split(StrConv(sIn, vbUnicode), Chr(0))
    'provided by Fencliff at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/342725-split-string-into-array.html

End Function

Function StringToNumber(MyString As String) As Integer

    Dim StringArray() As String
    Dim NumberArray() As Long

    StringArray() = StringToCharArray(MyString)

    ReDim NumberArray(UBound(StringArray))

    For i = LBound(StringArray) To UBound(StringArray)
        NumberArray(i) = Asc(StringArray(i))
    Next i

    StringToNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(NumberArray)

End Function
```

Comment: Whoever came up with the `StringToCharArray` function should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an example of "abc" the Split obtains an array "a", "b", "c", "". That is, with an empty string element at the end. This cannot be converted to an ascii number so causes the error.

A simplistic solution is to skip this last element:

```
For i = LBound(StringArray) To UBound(StringArray) - 1
```

I suspect the problem (the extra element) is related to the use of Unicode but I haven't investigated this.

Comment: That's it! If I had checked the array length I might have caught the extra character. Thanks!

Comment: If `MyString` contains a terminating separator (`Chr(0)` in this case) then `Split` will put an empty entry on the end. You could `Trim(MyString)` if there's no chance you're going to destroy other whitespace you care about.